# Sending ArrayList<integer>() into byte[] format thru USB in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, usb

My code uses a Modbus CRC16 protocol, which generates a `List<Integer>` with the hexadecimal values that must be written on the USB port.

[image]

I'm trying to convert this ArrayList containing Integer objects to a byte[] array so I can write it via USB.

I tried to implement using `IntBuffer` but got no success.

```
public static void SendKey(List<Integer> lst, int deviceaddr, int Key)
        {
            lst.add(deviceaddr & 0xff);
            lst.add(6);
            lst.add(0);
            lst.add(99);
            lst.add((Key >> 8) & 0xff);
            lst.add(Key & 0xff);
            Add_CRC16(lst);

            int[] data = toIntArray(lst);

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 4);        
            IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
            intBuffer.put(data);

            byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();
            ftDev.write(array, array.length, true);

        }

private static void Add_CRC16(List<Integer> Data) {

        // Método detector de erros Cyclic Redundancy Check

        int SaveLo, SaveHi;
        int CRC16Lo = 0xFF;
        int CRC16Hi = 0xff;
        int CL = 0x1;
        int CH = 0xA0;

        for (int b : Data) {
            CRC16Lo ^= b;

            for (int flag = 0; flag < 8; flag++) {
                SaveHi = CRC16Hi;
                SaveLo = CRC16Lo;

                CRC16Hi = CRC16Hi / 2;
                CRC16Lo = CRC16Lo / 2;

                if ((SaveHi & 0x01) == 0x01)
                    CRC16Lo |= 0x80;

                if ((SaveLo & 0x01) == 0x01) {
                    CRC16Hi ^= CH;
                    CRC16Lo ^= CL;
                }
            }

        }

            Data.add(CRC16Lo & 0xff);
            Data.add(CRC16Hi & 0xff);

    }
```

Should I use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `DataOutputStream`?

Comment: Well what format do you want the result to have? You could just use an `IntBuffer`, for example...

Comment: How do you mean "convert?"  What are you expecting?  A serialized object?  Integers values converted numerically to byte values?  Something else?

Comment: I need to get a byte[] array to send via USB FTDI. But it uses a Modbus CRC16 protocol, which generates a List<Integer>

Comment: Is this an Android device?  If not then what platform, please?

Comment: Yes, it's an Android application sending data to a microcontroller with a usb ftdi serial port.

Comment: I'm able to send and receive bytes[] but since they're not in the modbus sequence the microcontroller can't understand what's coming.

Comment: @markspace please check the edits

Comment: @JonSkeet do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any indication of the format - you've given one example of the byte array, but not of the input that would create that. (What endianness do you need?) I've already suggested using an IntBuffer - have you tried that?

Comment: @JonSkeet just added implementation of IntBuffer which unfortunately doesn't work. Not sure if endianesss matters in this situation. The outside board is written in C.

Comment: You've got 6 integers there - that's 24 bytes of information. Did you really just want one byte per integer? (This is the sort of thing I've been asking for the last two hours - a straightforward "here's the input, here's the expected output"...) And what does `Add_CRC16` do, exactly?

Comment: The expected output (from the outside board point of view) is a 16 bit Word "data item". Since Java doesn't hold a Word variable like Delphi does, which is a unsigned one, I had to work with int to make it possible. Add_CRC16 (which is now included) is a cyclic redundancy check method for Modbus communication.

Comment: That's *still* not what I asked for though. All I've asked for - repeatedly - is sample input (a list of integers) and expected output (a byte array). You still haven't shown that. I'll add an answer which is only a *guess* based on the code you've provided, but I don't see why you haven't just provided the samples...

Comment: @JonSkeet please check the edit, I believe now you might understand better the sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what output you're expecting, but given your example code, I suspect you just want:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte) list.get(i).intValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but got no succcess

Comment: @Machado: "got no success" tells us *nothing* about what's wrong here. The sample input/output you've given is exactly what this code would produce. What's different between what you saw and what you expected to see?

Comment: Whenever you send this 8 byte array to the microcontroller, if it's correct, it will set an operation mode on it and send back an 8 byte array of information. I'm getting back the 8 bytes from it, but no operation mode is being set. If the information that is being sent is 100% correct, it would work. It can't have a linebreak by the end of it, it **must** be exactly a command of 8 bytes.

Comment: @Machado: That doesn't answer my question. What did you expect the output of this code to be, compared with what it was? You asked about converting a `List<Integer>` to a `byte[]` - that's the code I've provided, following the example you've given. If that doesn't work for you, then the problem isn't in this code - it's in your specifications, effectively. Maybe your CRC check isn't working appropriately. Maybe you've got invalid data in some other sense. That's out of the scope of what you asked, which is how to convert a `List<Integer>` to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Well, that's something else going on then. Since you did answer my question, I will accept it and keep trying to solve it completely.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert any object into a byte array with this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
o.writeObject(objectToConvert);
return b.toByteArray();
```

Comment: You can, but that's almost certainly *not* going to be in the format the OP wants.